Balloon Going Up Problem - Related Rates: why is tan(x) the right solution and not sin(x) despite knowing all the sides
The question: A hot air balloon rises at a rate of 8 feet per second from a point on the ground 60 feet from an observer. Find the rate of change of the angle of elevation when the balloon is 25 feet above the ground.

My Solution:
$$\sin\theta = \frac{h}{65}$$
$$(\cos\theta)\cdot \frac{d\theta}{dt}= \frac{1}{65}\cdot \frac{dh}{dt}$$
$$\frac{60}{65}\cdot \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{1}{65}\cdot 8$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{8}{60}$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{2}{15}$$
However, this solution is incorrect. I am not sure why my solution of using $\sin\theta$ is incorrect. On the answer key, the solution used $\tan\theta$ and got a different answer. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Whatever equation you write to relate $\theta$ and $h$, it must be true not only for one value of $h$, because in order for derivatives to exist, $h$ must be able to change. You know that $\sin\theta=\frac{h}{65}$ at the instant when $h=25$ (not $35$) as shown in the figure. One second later, is that formula still true? Is the formula ever true for any other value of $h$?

Thank you for the explanation. I corrected the 35 to a 25 for the height. I appreciate your time.

If you use $\sin$, you have to take care that the hypotenuse is not constant: it is not 65, but $\sqrt{h^2+60^2}$, so you'd need to start with
$$\sin\theta = \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+60^2}}$$
Then you get:
\begin{align}
\cos\theta\dot{\theta} &= \frac{60^2 \dot{h}}{ (h^2+60^2)^{3/2}}\\
\dot{\theta}&= \frac{60^2\times 8}{(60/65)65^3}\\
&= \frac{60\times 8}{65^2}
\end{align}
This is the same as you get from using $\tan$:
\begin{align}
\sec^2\theta\dot{\theta} &= \frac{\dot{h}}{60}\\
\dot{\theta} &= \frac{(60/65)^28}{60}\\
\end{align}

I understand now; the hypotenuse is not constant is always changing, so I can't use  65 feet when solving in terms of sin. Thank you so much!
